# dynamic file upload path with current instance id

Tags: django, file-upload, django-views

I have a form which gets current logged in user, some inputs and a file:

```
class AddItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['user']
```

For this form a have a view:

```
item_form = AddItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if item_form.is_valid():
    item = item_form.save(commit=False)
    item.user = request.user
    item.save()
```

for this item's file field i am using upload_to feature. here is my modal:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    cover_image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

def get_upload_path(instance, filename):

    return "items/user_{user_id}/item_{item_id}/{filename}".format(user_id=instance.user.id, item_id=instance.id,filename=filename)
```

problem is that i can't see the current instance id in uploaded path because of following line:

```
item = item_form.save(commit=False)
```

it has not instance id yet and instead of current item id it create user_1/item_NONE/file

how can i set id to this path?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `instance.id` in `get_upload_path` for a new record, because the property hasn't been assigned at that point. It would only work when updating an existing record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pandemoniumillusion.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/django-imagefield-and-filefield-dynamic-upload-path-in-newforms-admin/) I've found idea && code based on using the post_save signal, when object created move from temp directory to specified one in model class:

> use_key and upload_to are optional. use_key defaults to False. If it is True then the id of the instance will be used as a prefix for the new file as there is the potential for overwriting now that we are moving the file. upload_to will simply define the temporary directory to upload the files to initially.

```
from django.db.models import ImageField, FileField, signals
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
from django.conf import settings
import shutil, os, glob, re
from distutils.dir_util import mkpath

class CustomImageField(ImageField):
    """Allows model instance to specify upload_to dynamically.

    Model class should have a method like:

        def get_upload_to(self, attname):
            return 'path/to/{0}'.format(self.id)
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['upload_to'] = kwargs.get('upload_to', 'tmp')

        try:
            self.use_key = kwargs.pop('use_key')
        except KeyError:
            self.use_key = False

        super(CustomImageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        """Hook up events so we can access the instance."""
        super(CustomImageField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        dispatcher.connect(self._move_image, signal=signals.post_save, sender=cls)

    def _move_image(self, instance=None):
        """
            Function to move the temporarily uploaded image to a more suitable directory 
            using the model's get_upload_to() method.
        """
        if hasattr(instance, 'get_upload_to'):
            src = getattr(instance, self.attname)
            if src:
                m = re.match(r"%s/(.*)" % self.upload_to, src)
                if m:
                    if self.use_key:
                        dst = "%s/%d_%s" % (instance.get_upload_to(self.attname), instance.id, m.groups()[0])
                    else:
                        dst = "%s/%s" % (instance.get_upload_to(self.attname), m.groups()[0])
                    basedir = "%s%s/" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, os.path.dirname(dst))
                    mkpath(basedir)
                    shutil.move("%s%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, src),"%s%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, dst))
                    setattr(instance, self.attname, dst)
                    instance.save()

    def db_type(self):
        """Required by Django for ORM."""
        return 'varchar(100)'


class Image(models.Model):
    file = CustomImageField(use_key=True, upload_to='tmp')

    def get_upload_to(self, attname):
        return 'path/to/{0}'.format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this function to the model :

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        saved_image = self.cover_image
        self.cover_image = None
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cover_image = saved_image
    else:
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You should also add `self.save()` at the end of the `if` block (before `else`). Otherwise it wont save.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to the new way of use signals for newer versions of django:

```
from django.db.models import ImageField, FileField, signals
from django.conf import settings
import shutil, os, glob, re
from distutils.dir_util import mkpath

class CustomImageField(ImageField):
    """Allows model instance to specify upload_to dynamically.

    Model class should have a method like:

        def get_upload_to(self, attname):
            return 'path/to/{0}'.format(self.id)
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['upload_to'] = kwargs.get('upload_to', 'tmp')

        try:
            self.use_key = kwargs.pop('use_key')
        except KeyError:
            self.use_key = False

        super(CustomImageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        """Hook up events so we can access the instance."""
        super(CustomImageField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        signals.post_save.connect(self._move_image, sender=cls)

    def _move_image(self, instance, **kwargs):
        """
            Function to move the temporarily uploaded image to a more suitable directory 
            using the model's get_upload_to() method.
        """
        if hasattr(instance, 'get_upload_to'):
            src = getattr(instance, self.attname)
            if src:
                m = re.match(r"%s/(.*)" % self.upload_to, str(src))
                if m:
                    if self.use_key:
                        dst = "%s/%d_%s" % (instance.get_upload_to(self.attname), instance.id, m.groups()[0])
                    else:
                        dst = "%s/%s" % (instance.get_upload_to(self.attname), m.groups()[0])
                    basedir = "%s/%s/" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, os.path.dirname(dst))
                    mkpath(basedir)
                    shutil.move("%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, src),"%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, dst))
                    setattr(instance, self.attname, dst)
                    instance.save()

    def db_type(self):
        """Required by Django for ORM."""
        return 'varchar(100)'
```